# leverage browser caching - expires or max-age, last-modified or etag

Tags: caching, browser

I'm having difficulty finding a clear-cut, practical explanation for what is the correct way to leverage browser caching to increase page speed.

According to [this site](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html#LeverageBrowserCaching):

> It is important to specify one of Expires or Cache-Control max-age,
>   and one of Last-Modified or ETag, for all cacheable resources. It is
>   redundant to specify both Expires and Cache-Control: max-age, or to
>   specify both Last-Modified and ETag.

Is this correct? If so, should I use `Expires` or `max-age`? I think I have a general understanding of what both of those are but don't know which is usually best to use.

If I have to also do `Last-Modified` or `ETag`, which one of those? I think I get `Last-Modified` but am still very fuzzy on this `ETag` concept.

Also, which files should I enable browser caching for?

Answer (score 72):

> Is this correct?

Yes, Expires and max-age do the same thing, but in two different ways. Same thing with Last-Modified and Etag

> If so, should I do
> expires or max-age?

Expires depends on accuracy of user's clock, so it's mostly a bad choice (as most browsers support HTTP/1.1). Use max-age, to tell the browser that the file is good for that many seconds. For example, a 1 day cache would be:

Cache-Control: max-age=86400

Note that when both `Cache-Control` and `Expires` are present, `Cache-Control` takes precedence. [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7549558/2458438)

> If I have to also do Last-Modified or ETag, which one of those? I think I get Last-Modified

You're right, Last-Modified should be better. Although it's a time, it's sent by the server. Hence no issue with user's clock. It's the reason why Last-Modified is better than Expires.
The browser sends the Last-Modified the server sent last time it asked for the file, and if it's the same, the server answsers with an empty response «304 Not Modified»

Also, you must note that ETag can be useful too, because Last-Modified has a time window of one second. So you can't distinguish two different sources with the same Last-Modified value. [2]

Etag needs some more computing than Last-Modified, as it's a signature of the current state of the file (similar to a md5 sum or a CRC32).

> Also, which files should I enable browser caching for?

All files can benefit caching. You've got two different approaches:

- with max-age: useful for files that never change (images, CSS, javascript). For as long as the max-age value, the browser won't send any request to the server. So you'll see the page loading really fast on the second load. If you need to update files, just append a question mark, and the date of change (for example /image.png?20110602, or for better proxies caching, something like /20110602/image.png or /image.20110602.png). This way you can make files expire if it's urgent (remember that the browser almost never hits the server once it has a max-age file). Main use is to speed things up and limit requests sent to the server.
- with Last-Modified: can be set on all files (including those with max-age). Even if you have dynamic pages, you may not change the content of the file for a while (even if it's 10 min), so that could be useful. The main use here is to tell the browser «keep asking me for this file, if it's new, I'll send you the new one». So, there's a request sent on each page load, but the answer is empty if the file is already good (304 Not Modified), so you save on bandwidth.

The more you cache, the faster your pages will show up. But it's a difficult task to flush caches, so use with care.

A good place to learn all this with many explanations: http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

[2]: rfc7232 Etag https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.3

Comment: Thanks for providing that explanation. However, I'm still having a difficult time trying to learn about how to actually implement your suggestions for max-age and last-modified. Where can I find some examples of the actual code I would put in my htaccess for these? Do I need to list each image? I think I basically understand the concept here, but need a little more explicit help on what this would look like in the htaccess.

Comment: See examples in the Apache's manual: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/fr/mod/mod_expires.html (Module Expires). For example: ExpiresByType image/gif M604800 will expire GIF images after 7 days (7*86400) after their own modification time. You'll find many other examples on the same page. Last-Modified may be sent too, but I don't use Apache, hence I didn't test this.

Comment: The Apache url is broken, but lives on in archive.org here: (fr) https://web.archive.org/web/20120418030430/http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/fr/mod/mod_expires.html or https://web.archive.org/web/20120418030430/http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/en/mod/mod_expires.html (en)

Comment: Adding the permalink (without version, but currently 2.4): http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html